# How to make a static tree view in odoo with fixed rows where first column contains some hard coded value and 2nd and 3rd column is editable

Tags: python, xml, odoo

How to make a static tree view in odoo with fixed number of rows where first column contains some hard coded value and 2nd column is editable. When user will go to crate new record button there will be a tree view with first column having some pre defined value and user only input in other columns and save the table data with 3 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Create tree view with following view syntax:

```
    <tree editable="top" string="Timesheet Activities" import="false"> 
       <field name="field1" readonly="1"/>
       <field name="field2" />
       <field name="field3" />
    </tree>
```

For python use default value for the field ie.

```
field1 = fields.Char(string="any string" default="Hard coded values")
field2 = fields.Char()
field3 = fields.Char()
```

Comment: what if I have 6 hard coded values and I want 6 static rows ?

Comment: If the hard-coded values are subject to change, you can use default functions. However, if you want static data, you can simply create six fields.